# why my Kendo drop down list does not bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

My kendoDropDown list is making me crazy! There is data in the datasource but it doesn't show it when I open it! I bound it with the following ajax (the last line is binding part):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",

    url: "@Url.Action("modelProducer","AdminTool")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "turbineType": s, }),
    success: function(data) {
        modelProducerResult = data;
        myData = data;
        var ddl = $("#ModelProducer").data("kendoDropDownList");
        // ddl.dataSource.data({}); // clears dataSource
        //ddl.dataSource.data({});
        ddl.text(""); // clears visible text
        ddl.value("");
        // $("#ModelProducer").empty();
        $("#ModelProducer").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(modelProducerResult);
    }
});
```

Here is my drop down list, the data comes from ajax, which has the data but the drop down list doesn't open!

```
function modelProducer(container, options) {
    var t = modelProducerResult;

    $('<input  name="ModelProducer" id="ModelProducer" data-type="string" style="width: 100%"\">')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: modelProducerResult,
            dataTextField: "model",
            dataValueField: "model",
            valuePrimitive: true,
            ServerFiltering: true
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about refreshing your datasource with

```
$("#ModelProducer").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
```

Also I'm not sure about your setting of `ServerFiltering: true` etc. Maybe you could use the default kendo-way to bind to remote data [like here in the demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource)?

**Update 1**

I've made a [JSFiddle simulating your situation](https://jsfiddle.net/LordMsz/xvdov7hc/) and it seems it might be a problem with jQuery version. Running the demo on `edge jQuery` it doesn't open.

Changing jQuery to 2.1.3 it seems to work.

Can you confirm this? What version do you use?
Check out kendo ui docs (docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites - sorry, can't post 3 links on SO :-/) for compatibility info.

Comment: @bravo83 Did you try $("#ModelProducer").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.query();

Comment: Please see my updated answer - jQuery version. You can open your javacript console and see if there are any errors during openning of the drop down. If there are any, I guess it's the problem with version mentioned above... Cheers